# How to implement firebase cloud function for android app

Tags: javascript, android, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I’m trying to develop a quiz game app using firestore. I would like to provide a ranking system for users. To achieve this, I’m querying user documents by categories and create a new leaderboard document. I tested it with java and it works fine (see code below). But now I would like to create a firebase cloud function for that purpose. It would be awesome if I could schedule the function to run twice a day (to limit read and write operations) or by triggering it by an url call. It looks like firebase supports both possibilities. Unfortunately, I don’t have any knowledge in neither javascript nor in typescript. Therefore I would like to ask here if someone could convert the java code below into a javascript code for firebase cloud function with the ability of scheduling the function to run at certain time or by triggering it through a url request?

```
        final HashMap<String, Map<String, Long>> rankingsColl = new HashMap<>();
        final Map<String, Long> cat1Map = new HashMap<>();
        final Map<String, Long> cat2Map = new HashMap<>();
        final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference users = db.collection("usersColl");
        users.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("stats.category1", 9)
                .orderBy("stats.category1", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(5).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    try {
                        String name = documentSnapshot.get("data.name").toString();
                        String code = documentSnapshot.get("data.code").toString();
                        long value = (long)documentSnapshot.get("stats.category1");
                        String fullName = name + " (" + code + ")";
                        cat1Map.put(fullName, (long)value);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                rankingsColl.put("category1", cat1Map);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        users.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("stats.category2", 7)
                .orderBy("stats.category2", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(5).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    try {
                        String name = documentSnapshot.get("data.name").toString();
                        String code = documentSnapshot.get("data.code").toString();
                        long value = (long)documentSnapshot.get("stats.category2");
                        String fullName = name + " (" + code + ")";
                        cat2Map.put(fullName, (long)value);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                rankingsColl.put("category2", cat2Map);

                db.collection("Leaders").document("Leaderboard").set(rankingsColl).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        System.out.println("ranking works");
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("error creating rankings");
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

That’s what I achieved so far by reading firebase docs. I think these queries should work. But I have no idea how to get out the desired data out of each document, add it to a map, create a new document based on the newly created map and put all the work into a function.

```
var users = db.collection('usersColl');
var query = users.where('stats.category1', '>', 9).orderBy('stats.category1', 'desc').limit(5).get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('No matching documents.');
      return;
    }  

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
      // put desired fields of each document into a map1
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });

var query2 = users.where('stats.category2', '>', 7).orderBy('stats.category1', 'desc').limit(5).get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('No matching documents.');
      return;
    }  

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
      // put desired fields of each document into a map2
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });

// create a new map<String, Map>, put map1 and map2 into this map and create a new document in firestore
```

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for providing the links. Actually, I just wanted to implement this one function and therefore I searched for a simpler way. But if there isn't one, I guess I have to swallow the pill and learn JavaScript.